# Releasing bound ports on process exit

Tags: c, networking, sockets

How do I make sure that a socket bound to a port is properly released on process exit such that the port can be reused without `bind()` failing with EADDRINUSE? I've written a tiny program which just creates a socket, binds it to a fixed port, waits for a connection and then immediately terminates. When I rerun the program, the `bind()` call fails with EADDRINUSE, but if I wait a few minutes, it succeeds.

Is there a way I can explicitly "unbind" the socket, thereby freeing the port number?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Using SO_REUSEADDR socket option will allow you to re-start the program without delay.

```
int iSetOption = 1;
...
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
setsockopt(_sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&iSetOption,
        sizeof(iSetOption))
...
```

Comment: But note that technically, using SO_REUSEADDR violates the TCP/IP protocol, making it possible (though unlikely) for the next program that binds that port to pick up packets intended for the original program.

Answer (score 5):

TCP/IP stack keeps port busy for sometime even after `close()` - socket will stay in `TIME_WAIT` and `TIME_WAIT2` state.

If I'm not mistaken, usually it takes 2 minutes so if you need to use the same port immediately set `SO_REUSEADDR` option on your socket before binding, just like Ivo Bosticky suggested.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but for completeness:

On Windows you can set the 
[TcpTimedWaitDelay](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938217.aspx) registry value to set the timeout for releasing closed TCP connections to as low as 30 seconds.