# How to avoid TIME_WAIT for server sockets?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I know you will mask this as duplicate ([question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592747/bind-error-while-recreating-socket), [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241144/socket-remains-open-after-program-has-closed-c), [question3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747272/tcp-socket-close-and-rebind)) but the answers are not what I'm looking for (and I think also other people). 
So, I'm refering to socket masters (I love you guys): how can I get bind error(address already in use) if I close the socket? 
I will describe my problem.

> I've got a client that communicate with a **server** 
>   In the server, I have two sockets: sockS (the main socket, that listens) and sockTX (the client one)
>   If I call my programs once, the communication is fine, then I close **both** sockets 
>   If I recall server and client, I get the error and I've to wait the TIME_WAIT (~3 minutes seconds on Ubuntu 32bit)

Why, after closing **both** sockets I still get bind error? 
 
There's a way to make it works without any magic (SO_REUSEADDR)? 
I know something in my code is wrong... 
Thank you everyone.
 
**That's the code**: 
Client

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 5000
#define SERVER "127.0.0.1"
#define MAXLINE 128

int printMessage(char* str);

int main(){
char buff[MAXLINE+1];

struct sockaddr_in server, client;
struct hostent *host;
int sock, n;
//socklen_t len;

    if((sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)) == -1){
        perror("\nErrore socket()");
        return -1;
    }

    client.sin_family = AF_INET;
    client.sin_port = htons(0); // la porta e' scelta dal sistema operativo
    client.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if( bind(sock,(struct sockaddr*)&client, sizeof(client)) == -1){
        perror("\nErrore bind()");
        return -1;
    }

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    if((host = gethostbyname(SERVER)) == NULL ){
        perror("\nErrore gethostbyname()");
        return -1;
    }

    server.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)host->h_addr);

    if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0){
        perror("\nErrore connect");
        return -1;
    }

    // MESSAGGIO

    sprintf(buff, "CTX\nclientTX\nserver\nCiao da client\n");
    if(send(sock, buff, strlen(buff), 0) < 0) {
        perror("\nErrore sendto");
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        printf("\nMessaggio inviato");
    }

    if((n = recv(sock, buff, MAXLINE, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("\nErrore ricezione risposta");
        return -1;
    } else {
        buff[n] = '\0';
        int test = printMessage(buff);
        printf("\nEsito: %s\n", (test == 1 ? "OK" : "FAIL"));
    }

    shutdown(sock, 2); // 2 = RD_WR
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}

int printMessage(char* str){
int i;
char* temp;

    printf("Mittente: ");
    for(i = 0; str[i] != '\n'; i++)
        printf("%c", str[i]);
    printf(" ");
    for(i = i+1; str[i] != '\n'; i++)
        printf("%c", str[i]);
    printf("\nDestinatario: ");
    for(i = i+1; str[i] != '\n'; i++)
        printf("%c", str[i]);

    temp = (char*)malloc(30 * sizeof(char));
    strncpy(temp, str+i+1, 30);
    printf("Messaggio: %s\n", temp);

    if(strcmp(temp, "OK") == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 5000
#define SERVER "127.0.0.1"
#define MAXLINE 128

int printMessage(char* str);

int main() {
char buff[MAXLINE+1];
struct sockaddr_in server; //, client;
int sockS, sockTX, n;

    if((sockS = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("\nErrore socket()");
        return -1;
    }

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if(bind(sockS, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) == -1)
    {
        perror("\nErrore bind()");
        return -1;
    }

    if(listen(sockS, 10) == -1)
    {
        perror("\nErrore listen()");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("SERVER\nInizializzazione completata!\n");

    if((sockTX = accept(sockS, (struct sockaddr *)NULL, NULL)) == -1)
    {
        perror("\nErrore accept()");
        return -1; 
    }
    printf("Socket connesso\n");

    // INVIO
    if((n = recv(sockTX, buff, MAXLINE, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("\nErrore recv()");
        return -1; // BREAK??

    } else {
        buff[n] = '\0';
        printMessage(buff);

    }

    sprintf(buff, "S\nserver\nclientTX\nOK\n");
    if(send(sockTX, buff, strlen(buff), 0) < 0){
        perror("\nErrore send()");
        return -1; // BREAK??

    } else {
        printf("Risposta inviata\n");

    }

    shutdown(sockTX, 2);
    close(sockTX);

    shutdown(sockS, 2);
    close(sockS);
    return 0;   
}

int printMessage(char* str){
int i;
char* temp;

    printf("Mittente: ");
    for(i = 0; str[i] != '\n'; i++)
        printf("%c", str[i]);
    printf(" ");
    for(i = i+1; str[i] != '\n'; i++)
        printf("%c", str[i]);
    printf("\nDestinatario: ");
    for(i = i+1; str[i] != '\n'; i++)
        printf("%c", str[i]);

    temp = (char*)malloc(30 * sizeof(char));
    strncpy(temp, str+i+1, 30);
    printf("Messaggio: %s\n", temp);

    if(strcmp(temp, "OK\n") == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Thank you everyone

**EDIT 1**: Possible solution (not very beautiful, but just a bit more than SOCK_REUSEADDR)
Try to add, before shutdown and close of the two server's socket, a sleep(1). 
The client will close before the server and it will work
Not very beautiful, I know. 
Or, better, before closing the first socket inside the server, you can check if the client closed the connection (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402549/check-if-socket-is-connected))

Comment: SO_REUSEADDR *is* the magic.

Comment: SO_REUSEADDR is not "magic"; it's the answer to your question. The fact that you don't like the correct answer is not a reason to repeat the question; the answer will not change.

Comment: Also: It's really a bad idea to bind a client socket to a specific port. Let the OS choose a port for you, and you won't have any problem. Only servers need well-known (fixed) ports.

Comment: @rici I wrote in on the first line (link no 1), and the reason why I decided to post the question, and I used a fixed PORT because I have a server..

Comment: @Duck I was looking for something a bit more 'elegant' :)

Comment: @Ignus, then you don't need socket masters, you have to talk to the TCP gods. It's just how it works. :)

Comment: @Duck ahah fortunatly, one of my teacher is really a TCP god :D I have another example that works perfectly, without magic, and it's very similar to the one I posted.. I'll try to work a bit more. However, thanks a lot :)

Comment: When you say "close both sockets", you mean `sockTX` and `sockS` in the server, right? You do not mean "the server socket and the client socket"?

Comment: So your question is basically: "Why is there TIME-WAIT for closing the accepting socket?"

Comment: @Ignus, then share your insight.  Maybe you were misunderstood.

Comment: @jxh Not exactly. I was asking if there's a standard-correct method that can close my socket, tells the operative system my connection is closed and let me reuse the PORT immediatly :)

Comment: @Ignus, those (your edit) are terrible solutions.  Think of a server handling thousands of connections.  Sleep the server a second for each one?  What if the client doesn't close w/i a second?  That is the point of time-wait to begin with.

Comment: @Duck oh :( you're right. The solution posted by jxh is better (very better). I just have problems with 'while(recv() < 0)'

Comment: @rici: One reason to *not* use `SO_REUSEADDR` is that it can mask a bug when there really is another server using the port. The asker didn't ask the question very well, but the question is whether there is a way to close a socket that avoids the TIME-WAIT state.

Comment: @jxh: It's true that `SO_REUSEADDR` needs to be used with caution, and it's also true that if the server and client are on the same machine and you are confident that the client will send a `FIN`, it's ok to wait for it (or, in other words, that solution also needs to be used with caution :) ). I agree, though, that you have provided a good answer to the question you just raised.

Comment: ARRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRDUINO!!! TASTY

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you follow the TCP state machine diagram, you will see that it is mandatory for the socket to transition to the TIME-WAIT state if the socket initiated sending the FIN. Using `shutdown(sockTX, 2)` without waiting for the client's FIN does exactly that.

If you want the server to wait for the client's FIN, you block on `recv()` waiting for a 0 return value first. Then, you can `close()`.

Note that unless you have duplicated the socket in some way (either with `dup*()` or with a `fork()` call), there is no need to call `shutdown()` if it is being immediately followed by a `close()`. You can just call `close()` (if the socket has been duplicated, the FIN will only be sent when the last copy is closed).

There is no need to `shutdown()` the accepting socket (`sockS`) at all.

So, I would change your server side to look something like the following to clean up the sockets:

```
while (recv(sockTX,...) > 0) {}
close(sockTX);

close(sockS);
```

Comment: Oh perfect :D I have just added a 'recv' before closing the first socket, and it works :D I tried just with the send but it gave me (obviously) some problems. (For now) it works. Thanks :D

Comment: Just one note: if I write while(recv() < 0); it waits forever. If I test the condition once, it works. Uhm the second case (the one that seems to works) is correct or no? I think no, because it's just coincidence that when I test the condition, the client have already closed the socket. Or what? Why the 'while(recv() < 0)' doesn't work?

Comment: `while (recv() < 0);` is nearly the opposite of my suggestion. What you want to do is wait for the client FIN, so you want to test if a 0 value is returned or an error. If you save the return value, you will see what value you received, and if it is less than 0, you should check what the error is.

Comment: yes sorry it was a misprint inside the comment. my code is while(1) {
  if(recv(sockTX, buff, MAXLINE, 0) < 0)
   break;
 }

Comment: With that version, the code with call `recv()` again if a 0 is returned, which is wrong. 0 return means FIN has arrived.

Comment: OOK I'm such a bad programmer. Changing my code into "while((n = recv()) >= 0) printf("%d\n", n);" I saw that recv returned 0. It is less than 0 and not less equal than 0. And jxh wrote it right. I'm wrong. Ok sockets taught me a hard lesson. Thankyou again man